# Why are acknowledgments used in WLAN but not in IEEE 802.3?

Tags: wifi, ieee

Just curious:
Why are acknowledgments used in WLAN but not in IEEE 802.3?
can anyone help please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because wireless(WLAN) network is not as reliable as wired(IEEE 802.3) network